# Path is wrong while running a job created for GitHub repository using webhook

Tags: jenkins, git, jenkins-pipeline

I am facing an issue of incorrect path while running a Jenkins job created for Github repository. As Jenkins is on my machine I have configured the webhook. The error I am facing is mentioned below.

```
FATAL: Could not checkout 23f50ab88eb784981883be5e59dec11b1d0de521
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f 23f50ab88eb784981883be5e59dec11b1d0de521" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: error: invalid path 'user/ Postman_Int_Github/postman_collection.json'

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2450)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$1100(CliGitAPIImpl.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2767)
Caused: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not checkout 23f50ab88eb784981883be5e59dec11b1d0de521
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2791)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1301)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:505)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1206)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1894)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

The line "invalid path 'user/ Postman_Int_Github/postman_collection.json'" implies something is wrong with the path. Try removing the leading blank space (before "Postman_Int_Github").

Comment: @Mate..i have not mentioned in this way..i have just provided my Github repository URL and it is putting space automatically.